# Oracle SQL developer - What is the easiest way to surround a list of texts with quotes and commas?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here's an example. I get the list like this below

```
99X2H19JBF11534
16B4H5FHCA12592
ABE4H5FHAA08646
SE0753207527
PAK810869145
PAK810714143
PAK810547887
PAK810340854
PAK820090918
```

I then use concatenate in excel (and surround the list with quotes and commas) to run queries like below in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
select * from admin.repair

where repair_nbr in (

'99X2H19JBF11534',
'16B4H5FHCA12592',
'ABE4H5FHAA08646',
'SE0753207527',
'PAK810869145',
'PAK810714143',
'PAK810547887',
'PAK810340854',
'PAK820090918');
```

I was wondering if other people have an easier way to surround the list with quotes and commas in Oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you got your list from a query, just drag and drop.

We'll not only quote the strings, we'll separate them with commas for you.

[image]

If you just have the text, SQL Developer also support block editing. Enable that on the Edit menu, then simply use down arrow to go through each line/curpos and select then paste the quotes.

Or if you're a fan of regex, the Search and Replace (ctrl+R) panel has a RegEx mode you can toggle on.

*Disclaimer: I'm a product manager at Oracle for SQL Developer.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got your list using query

```sql
select val from your_table order by whatever
```

change your query to

```sql
select 'select * from admin.repair where repair_nbr in ('
       || listagg('''' || val || '''', ',
' order by whatever)
       || ');'
from your_table
```

The result of auxiliar query is the query you require.

Note: You might get ORA-01489 if the result of concatenation is too long but it is different - yet still solvable - story (look for xmlagg function then).